# iOS: store two NSMutableArray in a .plist file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, nsmutablearray, plist

I want to store two NSMutableArray that I use as global array in AppDelegate. These two array are also store with NSUserDefaults. Now I want to know how I must create this file and how can I store these two array everytime I modify them. Can You help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Create an NSArray containing your two NSMutableArrays.

   ```
   NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:<#(id), ...#>, nil];
   ```
2. Write the array to a file.

   ```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *libraryDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *location = [libraryDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/somefilename.plist"];
   [array writeToFile:location atomically:YES];
   ```
3. Load the array from the file.

   ```
   NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"plist"];
   NSArry *array = (path != nil ? [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:location] : nil);
   ```

Comment: and when I save it again? I want replace it, how can I do?

Comment: Have you checked that your NSArrays aren't nil?

Comment: How to extract the NSMutableArray from the array (NSArray in the code)?