# Storing and Retrieving from a Plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, plist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS: store two NSMutableArray in a .plist file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070568/ios-store-two-nsmutablearray-in-a-plist-file)

I've always refrained from using plists as I'm not really sure how to use one.

Could anyone give a *simple* code example of using a plist? I'm interested in saving an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` to a plist and then retrieving it again later.

Are there any advantages/disadvantages to storing either an `NSArray` or an `NSDictionary`? Also, are there any rules with regards to what you can or can't store in a plist?

Comment: That only answers half the question, but thank you anyway.

Comment: Plists can't store all data types, just strings, numbers, booleans, dates, data, arrays, and dictionaries. There is no huge advantage of dictionary over array - if you want named keys use a dictionary and if you want an ordered list use an array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can store the following data types in a .plist file as value:

- NSArray
- NSMutableArray
- NSDictionary
- NSMutableDictionary
- NSData
- NSMutableData
- NSString
- NSMutableString
- NSNumber
- NSDate

With an NSDictionary you can store in a plist an associative array composed by some key-value pair. Use the NSArray if you only want to save a data series.

To save one of the object above on a plist file simply write:

```
- (NSString *)dataFilePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFileNameHere"];
}

 //Write to the plist

 [myArray writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];

 //Read from the plist

 if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
     NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question pretty well. One more thing though, when I'm calling `writeToFile:atomically:` I'm writing over the entire plist and not just appending data to the end of the file right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you want to append data to the older array you have to do it manually. Load the array, append then rewrite.